# Stuck on replacing array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I've used to site for many commands I had trouble using and it was very helpful. I thought you guys might be able to help me out and help me understand what i'm doing wrong here. The "Rabbit"/"R" is moving as I wanted, however the old position is not resetting its old value from the copied array. Logic for winning and losing aren't debugged, yet so ignore that.

EDIT*
I can't shorten the code due to the relations between the array has with the program. The precise description for the error is when the "Rabbit"/"R" moves from (Using representative values) GridCompOne[5][5] to GridCompOne[4][5] going "up" on the "grid" I have a second array called GridCompTwo which is a copied version of the first grid when the random values were generated. What is supposed to happen is the Rabbit's value, which = 4 is supposed to replace GridCompOne[4][5] to = 4 and the old position GridCompOne[5][5] is supposed to be replaced with GridCompTwo[5][5] old value being 3 which is supposed to represent the ground value I have assigned. But the replacing of the value doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SurvivalGameVersionTwo
{
    private int Repeat;
    public int WinLose = (1);
    private int Turn = (1);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String User;
        int Repeat = (0);

        //Creating Objects

        SurvivalGameVersionTwo game = new SurvivalGameVersionTwo();
        Score score = new Score();
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        Spawner spawner = new Spawner();
        Display display = new Display();
        User user = new User();
        Time time = new Time();
        Logic logic = new Logic();
        Movement movement = new Movement();

        //Calling object's class methods

        Intro();
        User = GetUser();
        user.setName(User);

        while (Repeat > 2);
        {

            game.Ready();
            grid.RandomGridGenerator();
            spawner.RabbitWolfSpawner();
            movement.Copy();

            while (game.WinLose <= 2)
            {
                display.UserGrid();
                game.Turn = Turns(game.Turn);
                movement.Movement();
                game.WinLose = logic.WinLose(game.Turn);
                time.Delay();
            }
            display.UserGrid();
            Repeat = Repeat();
            game.WinLose = (1);
        }
    }
    public static void Intro()
    {
        System.out.printf("Welcome to the Rabbit Survival Game!\n");
        System.out.println("Rules to win: Rabbit must cross the bridge.");
        System.out.println("Rules to lose: Rabbir drowns in the water, \n"+
                "eaten by the wolf, or starve to death in 30 turns.");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    }
    public static String GetUser()
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String Name;
        System.out.println("Please type in your name please.");
        Name = Input.next();
        return Name;
    }
    public static void Ready()
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String Ready;
        String Yes = ("Yes");
        String No = ("No");
        System.out.println("Are you ready to play?");
        System.out.println("Type in 'Yes', or 'No' to continue.");
        Ready = Input.next();
        if (Ready.equals(Yes) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Lets begin!!!");
        }
        else if (Ready.equals(No) == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye, and hope you come back to play again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("There was an error!!! Restart the program to try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static int Turns(int turns)
    {
        int Turns;
        System.out.printf("Turn %d.",turns);
        Turns = (turns + 1);
        return Turns;
    }
    public static int Repeat()
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int repeat;
        System.out.println("Do you wish to play again?");
        repeat = Input.nextInt();
        return repeat;
    }
}

class User
{
    private String Name;

    public void UserInfo(String name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Score
{
    public static int Total = 0;
    public static int Win = 0;
    public static int Lose = 0;
    public static double Ratio = 0;
}
class Grid {
    public static int[][] GridCompOne = new int[10][10];
    public static int[] Rabbit = new int[2];
    public static int[] Wolf = new int[2];

    public static void RandomGridGenerator() {
        Random r = new Random();

        int i = 1;
        int j = 1;
        int k = 0;
        int Low = 1;
        int High = 3;
        int Random;

        //parameters for bridge and water spawning

        while (k <= 9) {
            Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            GridCompOne[0][k] = Random;
            Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            GridCompOne[k][0] = Random;
            Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            GridCompOne[9][k] = Random;
            Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            GridCompOne[k][9] = Random;
            k++;
        }
        while (i <= 8) {
            while (j <= 8) {
                GridCompOne[i][j] = 3;
                j++;
            }
            j = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
class Spawner extends Grid
{
    public static void RabbitWolfSpawner()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int Low = 1;
        int High = 8;
        int XAxis;
        int YAxis;
        int Random;

        //Rabbit
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        XAxis = Random;
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        YAxis = Random;
        GridCompOne[XAxis][YAxis] = 4;
        Rabbit[0] = XAxis;
        Rabbit[1] = YAxis;
        //Wolf
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        XAxis = Random;
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        YAxis = Random;
        GridCompOne[XAxis][YAxis] = 5;
        Wolf[0] = XAxis;
        Wolf[1] = YAxis;
    }
}
class Movement extends Grid
{
    private static int[][] GridCompTwo = new int[10][10];

    public static void Copy()
    {
        System.arraycopy(GridCompOne, 0, GridCompTwo, 0, GridCompOne.length);
    }

    //Rabbit and Wolf Movement

    public static void Movement()
    {

        int High = 4;
        int Low = 1;

        Random R = new Random();

        int Random = R.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        //Rabbit
        switch (Random)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                //Up
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0] - 1][Rabbit[1]] = 4;
                Rabbit[0] = (Rabbit[0] - 1);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                //Down
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0] + 1][Rabbit[1]] = 4;
                Rabbit[0] = (Rabbit[0] + 1);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                //Left
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1] - 1] = 4;
                Rabbit[1] = (Rabbit[1] - 1);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                //Right
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
                GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1] + 1] = 4;
                Rabbit[1] = (Rabbit[1] + 1);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("There was an error!!!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        Random = R.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        //Wolf
        switch (Random)
        {
            case 1: {
                //Up
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0] - 1][Wolf[1]] = 5;
                Wolf[0] = (Wolf[0] - 1);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                //Down
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0] + 1][Wolf[1]] = 5;
                Wolf[0] = (Wolf[0] + 1);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                //Left
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1] - 1] = 5;
                Wolf[1] = (Wolf[1] - 1);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                //Right
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
                GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1] + 1] = 5;
                Wolf[1] = (Wolf[1] + 1);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                System.out.println("There was an error!!!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Display extends Movement
{
    private static char[][] GridUser = new char[10][10];
    public static void UserGrid()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char Letter = ' ';

        System.out.println("---------------------");

        while (i <= 9)
        {
            while (j <= 9)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
                switch (GridCompOne[i][j])
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        //Water
                        Letter = '~';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        //Bridge
                        Letter = '=';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        //Ground
                        Letter = ',';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4:
                    {
                        //Rabbit
                        Letter = 'R';
                        break;
                    }
                    case 5:
                    {
                        //Wolf
                        Letter = 'W';
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        //Error!!!
                        System.out.println("There was an error in the program!!!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                GridUser[i][j] = Letter;
                System.out.print(GridUser[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
class Logic extends Grid
{
    public static int WinLose(int counter)
    {

        int winlose = (0);
        if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==1)
        {
            System.out.println("The Rabbit has drowned!");
            System.out.println("Game over!");
            Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
            winlose = 3;
        }
        else if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==2)
        {
            System.out.println("The Rabbit has Escaped!");
            System.out.println("Game over!");
            Score.Win = Score.Win + 1;
            winlose = 3;

        }
        else if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==5)
        {
            System.out.println("The Rabbit has been Eaten by the Wolf!");
            System.out.println("Game over!");
            Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
            winlose = 3;
        }
        else if(counter>30)
        {
            System.out.println("The Rabbit has starved to death");
            System.out.println("Game over!");
            Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
            winlose = 3;
        }
            else
        {
            System.out.println(" (Next Turn in a couple seconds)");
        }
        return winlose;
    }
}
class Time
{
    public static void Delay()
    {
        try
        {
            long Seconds = (2000);
            Thread.sleep(Seconds);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're posting a lot of code and very little understandable description. Consider reversing this: posting much less code, and much *more* description of your code and your problem.

Comment: You should post the relevant code only.

Comment: please be more precise with your question so that you get a precise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause for the problem is `System.arraycopy`. As of my understanding it is copying reference instead of values (may be i am wrong).
i changed to manual copy then it is working fine up to the logic of replacing array. Please check below modified code with my comments

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SurvivalGameVersionTwo
{
private int Repeat;
public int WinLose = (1);
private int Turn = (1);

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String User;
    int Repeat = (3);//changed: to enter into while loop Repeat should be more than 2

    //Creating Objects

    SurvivalGameVersionTwo game = new SurvivalGameVersionTwo();
    Score score = new Score();
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    Spawner spawner = new Spawner();
    Display display = new Display();
    User user = new User();
    Time time = new Time();
    Logic logic = new Logic();
    Movement movement = new Movement();

    //Calling object's class methods

    Intro();
    User = GetUser();
    user.setName(User);

    while (Repeat > 2)//changed: removed ;
    {

        game.Ready();
        grid.RandomGridGenerator();
        movement.Copy();//changed:First copy then change GridCompOne array
        spawner.RabbitWolfSpawner();


        while (game.WinLose <= 2)
        {
            display.UserGrid();
            game.Turn = Turns(game.Turn);
            movement.Movement();
            game.WinLose = logic.WinLose(game.Turn);
            time.Delay();
        }
        display.UserGrid();
        Repeat = Repeat();
        game.WinLose = (1);
    }
}
public static void Intro()
{
    System.out.printf("Welcome to the Rabbit Survival Game!\n");
    System.out.println("Rules to win: Rabbit must cross the bridge.");
    System.out.println("Rules to lose: Rabbir drowns in the water, \n"+
            "eaten by the wolf, or starve to death in 30 turns.");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
}
public static String GetUser()
{
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String Name;
    System.out.println("Please type in your name please.");
    Name = Input.next();
    return Name;
}
public static void Ready()
{
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String Ready;
    String Yes = ("Yes");
    String No = ("No");
    System.out.println("Are you ready to play?");
    System.out.println("Type in 'Yes', or 'No' to continue.");
    Ready = Input.next();
    if (Ready.equals(Yes) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Lets begin!!!");
    }
    else if (Ready.equals(No) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Goodbye, and hope you come back to play again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error!!! Restart the program to try again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public static int Turns(int turns)
{
    int Turns;
    System.out.printf("Turn %d.",turns);
    Turns = (turns + 1);
    return Turns;
}
public static int Repeat()
{
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int repeat;
    System.out.println("Do you wish to play again?");
    repeat = Input.nextInt();
    return repeat;
}
}

class User
{
private String Name;

public void UserInfo(String name)
{
    this.Name=name;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
}

class Score
{
public static int Total = 0;
public static int Win = 0;
public static int Lose = 0;
public static double Ratio = 0;
}
class Grid {
public static int[][] GridCompOne = new int[10][10];
public static int[] Rabbit = new int[2];
public static int[] Wolf = new int[2];

public static void RandomGridGenerator() {
    Random r = new Random();

    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int k = 0;
    int Low = 1;
    int High = 3;
    int Random;

    //parameters for bridge and water spawning

    while (k <= 9) {
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        GridCompOne[0][k] = Random;
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        GridCompOne[k][0] = Random;
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        GridCompOne[9][k] = Random;
        Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        GridCompOne[k][9] = Random;
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= 8) {
        while (j <= 8) {
            GridCompOne[i][j] = 3;
            j++;
        }
        j = 1;
        i++;
    }
}
}
class Spawner extends Grid
{
public static void RabbitWolfSpawner()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    int Low = 1;
    int High = 8;
    int XAxis;
    int YAxis;
    int Random;

    //Rabbit
    Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    XAxis = Random;
    Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    YAxis = Random;
    GridCompOne[XAxis][YAxis] = 4;
    Rabbit[0] = XAxis;
    Rabbit[1] = YAxis;
    //Wolf
    Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    XAxis = Random;
    Random = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    YAxis = Random;
    GridCompOne[XAxis][YAxis] = 5;
    Wolf[0] = XAxis;
    Wolf[1] = YAxis;
}
}
class Movement extends Grid
{
 private static int[][] GridCompTwo = new int[10][10];

public static void Copy()
{
    //System.arraycopy(GridCompOne, 0, GridCompTwo, 0, GridCompOne.length);
    //changed
    //As of my understanding System.arraycopy is not coping values , it is copying references 
    for(int i=0;i<GridCompOne.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<GridCompOne[i].length;j++){
            GridCompTwo[i][j]=GridCompOne[i][j];
        }
    }
}

//Rabbit and Wolf Movement

public static void Movement()
{

    int High = 4;
    int Low = 1;

    Random R = new Random();

    int Random = R.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    //Rabbit
    switch (Random)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            //Up
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0] - 1][Rabbit[1]] = 4;
            Rabbit[0] = (Rabbit[0] - 1);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            //Down
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0] + 1][Rabbit[1]] = 4;
            Rabbit[0] = (Rabbit[0] + 1);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            //Left
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1] - 1] = 4;
            Rabbit[1] = (Rabbit[1] - 1);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            //Right
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]] = GridCompTwo[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]];
            GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1] + 1] = 4;
            Rabbit[1] = (Rabbit[1] + 1);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            System.out.println("There was an error!!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    Random = R.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    //Wolf
    switch (Random)
    {
        case 1: {
            //Up
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0] - 1][Wolf[1]] = 5;
            Wolf[0] = (Wolf[0] - 1);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            //Down
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0] + 1][Wolf[1]] = 5;
            Wolf[0] = (Wolf[0] + 1);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            //Left
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1] - 1] = 5;
            Wolf[1] = (Wolf[1] - 1);
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            //Right
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]] = GridCompTwo[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1]];
            GridCompOne[Wolf[0]][Wolf[1] + 1] = 5;
            Wolf[1] = (Wolf[1] + 1);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            System.out.println("There was an error!!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
}
class Display extends Movement
{
private static char[][] GridUser = new char[10][10];
public static void UserGrid()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char Letter = ' ';

    System.out.println("---------------------");

    while (i <= 9)
    {
        while (j <= 9)
        {
            System.out.print("|");
            switch (GridCompOne[i][j])
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    //Water
                    Letter = '~';
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    //Bridge
                    Letter = '=';
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    //Ground
                    Letter = ',';
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    //Rabbit
                    Letter = 'R';
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    //Wolf
                    Letter = 'W';
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    //Error!!!
                    System.out.println("There was an error in the program!!!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            GridUser[i][j] = Letter;
            System.out.print(GridUser[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
}
class Logic extends Grid
{
public static int WinLose(int counter)
{

    int winlose = (0);
    if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==1)
    {
        System.out.println("The Rabbit has drowned!");
        System.out.println("Game over!");
        Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
        winlose = 3;
    }
    else if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==2)
    {
        System.out.println("The Rabbit has Escaped!");
        System.out.println("Game over!");
        Score.Win = Score.Win + 1;
        winlose = 3;

    }
    else if(GridCompOne[Rabbit[0]][Rabbit[1]]==5)
    {
        System.out.println("The Rabbit has been Eaten by the Wolf!");
        System.out.println("Game over!");
        Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
        winlose = 3;
    }
    else if(counter>30)
    {
        System.out.println("The Rabbit has starved to death");
        System.out.println("Game over!");
        Score.Lose = Score.Lose + 1;
        winlose = 3;
    }
        else
    {
        System.out.println(" (Next Turn in a couple seconds)");
    }
    return winlose;
}
}
class Time
{
public static void Delay()
{
    try
    {
        long Seconds = (2000);
        Thread.sleep(Seconds);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I just want to make sure I understand the issue. If I use System.arraycopy the second array will reference from the first array and never really copy the values into it? Upon further changes to the first array after the System.arraycopy the second array will copy it as well at the instance?

Comment: @Killermarine101 if the above solution solves your problem ,please accept  my answer.